# How to run .py file in colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I wanna run this code from github (https://github.com/princeton-vl/DROID-SLAM/tree/main) in google colab, but when i follow the instuction in the google colab it has an error:

in this line:

python setup.py install

it has this error:

No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda'

what should i do?

i tried too many times but it didnt work

Comment: You need to enable GPU in your runtime. Go to *Runtime* on the top left bar then *Change runtime type* and then select *T4 GPU* to get CUDA access.